# std::for_each with boost::zip_iterator fails to compile

Tags: c++, boost

The following code fails to compile for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>

typedef boost::tuple<int&, float&> EntryTuple;

struct zip_func :
  public std::unary_function<EntryTuple&, void>
{
  void operator()(EntryTuple& t) const
  {
    std::cout << t.get<0>() << " " <<  t.get<1>() << std::endl;
  }
};


int main()
{

const int N = 5;
std::vector<int> intVec(N,2);
std::vector<float> valueVec(N,5.5);

std::for_each(
boost::make_zip_iterator(
  boost::make_tuple(intVec.begin(), valueVec.begin())
  ),
boost::make_zip_iterator(
  boost::make_tuple(intVec.end(), valueVec.end())
  ),
zip_func()
);

return 0;
}
```

Error message from [live example](https://ideone.com/foZdX0):

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/algorithm:62:0,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/utility/swap.hpp:24,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp:40,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/tuple/tuple.hpp:33,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp:19,
>                    from prog.cpp:4: /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of '_Funct
>   std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter =
>   boost::zip_iterator >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >, boost::tuples::null_type,
>   boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type,
>   boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type,
>   boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type,
>   boost::tuples::null_type> >; _Funct = zip_func]': prog.cpp:34:1:
>   required from here /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:3755:14:
>   error: no match for call to '(zip_func)
>   (boost::iterator_facade >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >, boost::tuples::null_type,
>   boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type,
>   boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type,
>   boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type,
>   boost::tuples::null_type> >, boost::tuples::cons >,
>   boost::random_access_traversal_tag, boost::tuples::cons >,
>   int>::reference)'   __f(*__first);
>                 ^ prog.cpp:9:8: note: candidate is:  struct zip_func :
>           ^ prog.cpp:12:8: note: void zip_func::operator()(EntryTuple&) const    void operator()(EntryTuple& t) const
>           ^ prog.cpp:12:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from
>   'boost::iterator_facade >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >, boost::tuples::null_type,
>   boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type,
>   boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type,
>   boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type,
>   boost::tuples::null_type> >, boost::tuples::cons >,
>   boost::random_access_traversal_tag, boost::tuples::cons >,
>   int>::reference {aka boost::tuples::cons >}' to
>   'EntryTuple& {aka boost::tuples::tuple&}'

If I add some `const`s, it [compiles](https://ideone.com/42k07U):

```
typedef boost::tuple<const int&, const float&> EntryTuple;

struct zip_func :
  public std::unary_function<const EntryTuple&, void>
{
  void operator()(const EntryTuple& t) const
  {
    std::cout << t.get<0>() << " " <<  t.get<1>() << std::endl;
  }
};
```

What is the reason?

Comment: Boost's zip iterator is a view-only iterator?  As an aside, `std::unary_function` is very C++03 of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GCC 5.1 produces a more understandable error message:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb11a1b0c474bbba)

> /usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:3767:5: error: invalid
>   initialization of non-const reference of type 'EntryTuple& {aka
>   boost::tuples::tuple&}' from an rvalue of type
>   'EntryTuple {aka boost::tuples::tuple}'

So `const` is just necessary for the operator's argument:

```
typedef boost::tuple<int&, float&> EntryTuple;

struct zip_func :
  public std::unary_function<const EntryTuple&, void>
{
  void operator()(const EntryTuple& t) const
  {
    t.get<0>() = 10;
    std::cout << t.get<0>() << " " <<  t.get<1>() << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Live example: https://ideone.com/hwC3bb